# Shouldn't terminal voltage be equal to EMF only when internal resistance is zero?

Tags: electromagnetism

For terminal voltage $V$, and EMF $E$, current $I$ and internal resistance $r$,

$V = E-ir$

So for $V = E$, $r$ should be zero.

I believe $i$ cannot be zero if there is a potential difference, right?
So the internal resistance must be zero, right?

Comment: It is possible to use perfect voltmeter meter's with the meter drawing no current: Check out my answer at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/258385/ohms-law-and-an-ideal-voltmeter/258405#258405

Comment: So it is possible that there be zero current even when there is a potential difference. But shouldn't the voltage cause electrons to move and therefore, current. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I believe $i$ cannot be zero if there is a potential difference, right?
>   So the internal resistance must be zero, right?

I have to assume that you've concluded this because you're thinking that $r$ is the *total* resistance in the circuit, i.e., that the source is short-circuited.  In that case, the terminal voltage is *zero* and the *short-circuit current* is

$$I_{SC} \equiv \frac{E}{r}$$

However, the source is typically connected to a *load* $R_L > 0$ which is in *series* with the internal resistance $r$.  Thus,

$$i = \frac{E}{R_L + r}\quad\Rightarrow\quad V = E \frac{R_L}{R_L + r}$$

Now, in the large $R_L$ limit, the terminal voltage $V$ approaches the emf:

$$\lim_{R_L\rightarrow\infty}V = E$$

which is why we say that the *open-circuit terminal voltage* $V_{OC}$ equals the emf $E$

$$V_{OC} = E$$

Looked at an equivalent way, when the source terminals are not connected to an external circuit (open circuit), the current $i$ is zero since $R_L + r = \infty$ and then

$V = E - 0\cdot r = E$

In summary, the internal resistance $r$ does not need to be zero in order for the terminal voltage $V$ to equal the emf $E$.

Comment: I understand the $V=E-0$ explanation. The current $i$ being zero makes sense to me there. But in the limit of $R_{L}$. It doesn't. 
$ \lim_{R_L \to \infty} \frac{E}{R_L + r}$ should be zero, right?

Comment: @RahulChhabra, $i\rightarrow 0$ as $R_L\rightarrow\infty$.  So $V = E$ when $R_L = \infty$  Imagine that you simply disconnect the load resistance from the source.  There is zero current $i$ through the internal resistance now, correct?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.

If you are talking about the terminal voltage of a voltage source, such as a battery, then the terminal voltage under load ($i$ not equal to 0) will equal the open circuit (no load, or $i=0$) voltage (EMF, or E in your equation) only for an ideal voltage source (i.e., ideal battery), which is one where $r=0$.

Hope this  helps.

Comment: @Bob D, the answer to the title question is *no*.  Otherwise, the open-circuit voltage of a source with non-zero internal resistance would not equal the emf.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I was answering the question as phrased in the last sentence of the text. The answer to the question as phrased in the title is no but only if no current is drawn from the source. But I think that should be clear from the text of my answer, i.e., terminal voltage equals EMF if i=0, irrespective of r. What's more, my answer was based on $r$ only being the source resistance, and not the total resistance of the circuit.

Comment: @RahulChhabra Just to be clear, is the $r$ you are talking about only the internal resistance of, say, a battery, or the total resistance of the circuit, battery plus load resistance. My answer was based on the former.

Comment: $r$ is internal resistance. Thanks guys for the help. 