# Will ideal voltmeter show any deflection in its needle?

Tags: electric-circuits

If resistance would infinity it should not show any deflection so why its called ideal

Comment: An _ideal_ Volt meter doesn't have to "show deflection in a needle." It only has to tell you the Voltage difference between two distinct points. If you say "ideal," then there's no point in talking about how it works. You can't actually build an _ideal_ anything.

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* Raptor! I've voted to close your question as a duplicate of [Ohm's law and an ideal voltmeter](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/258385/9887). If, after reading the Q & A there, you still have a question, please edit your question to describe in detail what isn't still isn't clear.